# Websocket connection in Application Load Balancer AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

We are going to set up an Application Load Balancer(application layer) in AWS, our platform uses websockets and I wonder if once a connection was established, the Load balancer could send the current traffic of a websocket connection to another instance, it could be possible?

I mean, if my application establishes a websocket connection to the server through the balancer, all the traffic that I send using that websocket connection is going to finish at the same server?

I am aware that if a create a new websocket connection could be established in a different one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have notice that once the connection has been established between the client and the server the pipe keeps open until the connection is closed. So, all the traffic that I send using that websocket connection is going to finish at the same server

Answer (score 0):

This is only if you have:

1. A single server behind the ALB
2. Stickiness enabled on the ALB (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/40423241/9688617)