# How can I set up Web Sockets on AWS and log incoming messages to s3 (elastic beanstalk project) mysql db

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-api-gateway, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an existing LAMP project on AWS (Elastic-beanstalk). I now what to set up web sockets on AWS too. According to AWS documentation, the way to do that is via AWS API Gateway. I don't know how this all works but there's [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-websocket-api-integration-requests.html) I found for setting up WebSockets.

Does the Gateway API connect to another service? If so, what service is this? What am I missing?

I mostly just want to make a Web Socket service to look incoming messages to the MySQL database on my Elastic-beanstalk project. I am totally confused about how to do this. Can anyone advise me about what steps I need to take?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS doesn't support PHP (Ratchet) Web Sockets

Answer (score 0):

Just because api gateway supports web sockets,  doesn't mean you need to use it.   ALBs do as well and are a more exact fit for elastic beanstalk.

[Does an Application Load Balancer support WebSockets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39336033/does-an-application-load-balancer-support-websockets)

Comment: Thanks for this. I see here how this was set up in node.js. How do you do it in PHP / LAMP?