# Where to configure websockets with an application load balancer on AWS EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, websocket, aws-application-load-balancer

According to the [AWS documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/faqs/), "WebSockets and Secure WebSockets support is available natively and ready for use on an Application Load Balancer."

However, when I select Application Load Balancer in EC2, I don't have any option other than HTTP and HTTPS:

[image: Protocol options]

I would like to use the secure websocket protocol (wss://) which I believe would be over TLS:8888.

How can I input this option?

Comment: Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39336033/does-an-application-load-balancer-support-websockets). You have to use http or https for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use HTTPS for the listener protocol, even though the browser is making requests to wss://.

For port number, configuring both the listener and environment instance to port 8888 works.

Comment: What rules did you set on the listener? e.g. "Forward" or "Return fixed response"? Also, did you create a Target Group as is suggested in this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39336033/does-an-application-load-balancer-support-websockets

Comment: I have the same question ^^

Comment: I wanna read too

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Target Group with your port that websocket uses. Point that target group to the same EC2 instance.

Then create a new listener with websocket port and point the newly created Target Group.

This should work fine.