# Configure Ratchet and EC2 and AWS Load Balancer throws WebSocket connection to 'wss://chat.domain.com:8080/' failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, proxy, ratchet, aws-application-load-balancer

I have built a Websocket on Ubuntu 20.04 (LAMP) stack using Ratchet.

I followed this article https://www.twilio.com/blog/create-php-websocket-server-build-real-time-even-driven-application to build the websocket.

I Followed this article [Does an Application Load Balancer support WebSockets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39336033/does-an-application-load-balancer-support-websockets) to configure my webserver.

1. Configured Security Group - Inbound rules  TCP  8080
2. Configured Load balancer
3. Created Target group (TCP) for port 8080

[image]

4. Enabled Stickyness (1 hour)
5. SSL is configured and created in AWS Certificate Manager

[image]

5. Apache configuration

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName chat.domain.com
       ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
       DocumentRoot /var/www/websites/chat.domain.com/public
          <Directory /var/www/websites/chat.domain.com/public/>
              Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
              AllowOverride All
              Require all granted
          </Directory>

       ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/chat.domain.com/error.log
       CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/chat.domain.com/access.log combined
   </VirtualHost>

   <VirtualHost *:443>
       ServerName chat.domain.com
       ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
       DocumentRoot /var/www/websites/chat.domain.com/public
          <Directory /var/www/websites/chat.domain.com/public/>
               Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
               AllowOverride All
               Require all granted
           </Directory>

       ProxyPass / https://chat.domain.com:8080/
       ProxyPassReverse / https://chat.domain.com:8080/
       <Location "/">
           ProxyPass "wss://chat.domain.com:8080/"
       </Location>


       ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/chat.domain.com/error.log
       CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/chat.domain.com/access.log combined
   </VirtualHost>
   ```

Every thing is in place and running but I get

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://chat.domain.com:8080/' failed:

Here is my chrome inspect

[image]

I have even tried to Open traffic to ALL ports (Inbond) just to check the security group but still getting the same error.

I doubt the problem is configuring Load Balancer, Security Group and Target group?

Any help or suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution. The port 8080 should have been added to firewall and I had to create a new target group for port 8080 which then I had to create a load balancer with port http:8080 and point to the target group.

Comment: Hello, Can you please help me out with the same.

Comment: Open port 8080 (allow access) from the network of the server. it should solve the problem.